# How to immutably insert into a sorted array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, immutability

How do I immutably insert an element into a sorted array? (Let's assume an array of integers for simplicity)

The reason for this question: I'm writing a reducer for a React app, where the order of elements in my particular array is important.

The closest solution I've found is this [one here](https://daveceddia.com/react-redux-immutability-guide/#redux-insert-an-item-in-the-middle-of-an-array), but it doesn't cover insertions into a sorted array.

Comment: What do you mean by "immutably insert"? Inserting is a mutation. Sounds like you just need to make a copy of the array, insert into the copy, and return that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```js
let sortedArr = [1,2,5,9,12];

const newItem = 7;

for (let i = 0; i < sortedArr.length; i++) {
  if (newItem <= sortedArr[i]) {
    sortedArr = [...sortedArr.slice(0, i), newItem, ...sortedArr.slice(i)];
    break;
  }
}
console.log(sortedArr);
```